# How to get button link in alert box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In below code i am trying to get button href attribute value and show it in alert box using jquery.

When i click on button because of href value(i.e. $value['3']) it will redirect to our retailer link,But by using jquery when i get button link without page refresh by using href attribute it only take first link on any button link.
Actually i wan't that particular button link without page refresh.

```
 <html><head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script></head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.button').click(function(){
                var href = $('a').attr('href');
                alert(href);
            })
        });
    </script><body>
<?php
    $data=array(
    array("HTC desire 210 black","Flipkart",20000,"http://www.flipkart.com"),
    array("HTC desire 326 white","Snapdeal",22000,"http://www.snapdeal.com"),
    array("HTC desire 516","Amazon",23000,"http://www.amazon.in")
    );

    foreach($data as $value)
    {
    ?>


    <a href="<?php echo $value['3']; ?>"><input type="button" value="Get link's href value" class="button" /></a><br/><br/>
    <?php
    }
    ?></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change in script

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).on('click','.button',function(){
                    var href = $(this).attr('data-link');
                    alert(href);
                })
            });
        </script>
```

change in html

```
<input type="button" value="Get link's href value" class="button" data-link="<?php echo $value['3']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
                var href = $(this).parent('a').attr('href');
                alert(href);
            })
```

Comment: Ya it will works that i wan't,Thanks for your valuable support

Comment: how can i store the above "href" variable in session variable,were i can use elsewhere

Comment: try localstorage `localStorage.setItem('href',href);`

Comment: ok then how to echos this session variable in other page for testing.

Comment: `$('body').append(localStorage.getItem('href'));`

Comment: you are getting the value on click, when you print the value you need to click first and than show the value,right now you are getting the previous value clicked

Comment: ya absolutely right, right now i am getting previous value, but when i click on button then only it gives popup page using onclick event and in that page actually i echos the above session variable value(popup division will be show on without page load were loginpopup.php already included in our file)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to alert the href value of a link when you click on it? use preventDefault();

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
       alert( $(this).attr('href') );
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    })
});
```

Or if you want to click on a button only then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(e){
       alert( $(this).parent('a').attr('href') );
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: @shopeeon Happy to help. Don't forget to upvote/accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This this is work fine for me.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).closest('a').attr('href');
        alert(href);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com"><button class="button">Google</button></a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><button class="button">Yahoo</button></a>
<a href="http://www.msn.com"><button class="button">Bing</button></a>
```

Comment: @shopeeon is this actually you want?